# What are the best A/B tools?

Tags: tools, ab-testing

I have a few pages to A/B test, and I am looking for the best tools to use for this? Is there a "standard" or favorite industry tool?

Comment: If this question is about "Best" A/B tools, then I'd like to see motivation from answerers on why their tool is the best. Right now it's just a list of A/B tools which you could get by Googling. What can we do to improve the quality of answers here to make this a unique resource so people don't have to Google?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google offers a free AB tester callled [Website Optimizer](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer)

Answer (score 4):

I would advise you to try this new tool:
http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/

I think this should be the future of A/B testing! You can use it without any html/css knowledge. It is for business users, who know marketing and not programming.

And it is reasonably priced!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of [Optimizely](http://optimize.ly/hUoLG2).

Visual editing. Easy goal setting. Real-time reporting. Retroactive goal data. Simple to use interface.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Vertster and found it to be a worthy (though not free) tool for A/B and multivariate testing.

Answer (score 2):

Omniture (now Adobe's) [Test and Target](http://www.omniture.com/en/products/conversion/testandtarget)